# How to calculate standard deviation of an RDD in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing

I am a new Apache Spark user and am confused about the way that sparks run the programs.

For example, I have a large int RDD that is distributed over 10 nodes and want to run a scala code on the driver to calculate the (average/standard deviation) of each partition. (it is important to have these values for each partition, not for all of data).

Is it possible in Spark and could anyone give me a sample?

Comment: Can you be bit more clear with an example on what you want to achieve. This question is very vague considering åpache spark can be used for a map-reduce job. An

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni As I described, I want to calculate the partial standard deviation of some data that is distributed over 10 nodes. For example, if I have 500 numbers in 10 nodes, I want to calculate the StdDev of each 50 numbers which are located on each node. In other words, after running my program, I should have 10 numbers which are the StdDev of each 50 numbers. I hope I have been able to correctly put what I have meant.

Comment: Yes this is possible to be done across 10 Nodes. In spark it is more about executors running tasks. In your case assuming you have 10 executors (1 in each node) you can create RDD with a sc.parallelize() function to spread Integer[10][50].

Comment: OK. But I don't know what code should I write to distribute the task over the executors. Would you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

> A sample java code to do the spark map operation.

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList();

for(int j = 0 ; j < 10; j++){
   List<Integer> l = new ArrayList();
   for(int i = 0 ; i < 50; i++){
      l.add(i);
   }
   listOfLists.add(l);
}

SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("STD Application"); //set other params
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaRDD<List<Integer>> rddNumbers = sc.parallelize(listOfLists);

JavaRDD<Integer> partialSTD = rddNumbers.map(x -> Utils.std(x)); 

for(Integer value: partialSTD.collect()){
        System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: @hamidreza The above code does a simple map operation across by creating a spark context and prints the std of each list<50> integers.

Comment: Very good and thank you. can I replace any function with Utils.std(x) ? for example if I want to calculate the sum of odd numbers at each partition what should I write?

Comment: Yes you can replace Utils.std(x) with your function which has to be "serializable" which I forgot to mention. Please mark as answer if this solves your question! If you want to do this, you'll have to calculate another ```oddRDD = rddNumbers.map(x->Utils.OddnumberAdd(x)); ```

Comment: Ok. I do not want to use Utils functions and want to write the function myself. That is my main problem.